# Load Script only once in Next.js using React hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I want to use [Utterances](https://utteranc.es) for my blog. It should only load when someone scrolled to the bottom of the post so I use `react-intersection-observer` for that. I have made the following hook.

## useUtterances.ts

```
import React from 'react'
import { useTheme } from 'next-themes'

import { siteMetadata } from '@/_data/index'

export const useUtterances = (commentNodeId: string) => {
    const config = siteMetadata.comment.utterancesConfig
    // username/repo format
    const REPO_NAME = config.repo as string

    const { theme, resolvedTheme } = useTheme()
    const utterancesTheme =
        theme === 'light' || resolvedTheme === 'light' ? config.theme : config.darkTheme

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const scriptParentNode = document.getElementById(commentNodeId)
        if (!scriptParentNode) return

        // docs - https://utteranc.es/
        const script = document.createElement('script')
        script.src = 'https://utteranc.es/client.js'
        script.async = true
        script.setAttribute('repo', REPO_NAME)
        script.setAttribute('issue-term', 'pathname')
        script.setAttribute('label', 'comment :speech_balloon:')
        script.setAttribute('theme', utterancesTheme)
        script.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous')

        scriptParentNode.appendChild(script)

        return () => {
            // cleanup - remove the older script with previous theme
            scriptParentNode.removeChild(scriptParentNode.firstChild as Node)
        }
    }, [REPO_NAME, commentNodeId, utterancesTheme])
}
```

## Utterances.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer'

import { useUtterances } from '@/hooks/useUtterances'

export const Utterances = () => {
    const COMMENTS_NODE_ID = 'comments'
    const { ref, inView } = useInView({ threshold: 0, triggerOnce: true })

    useUtterances(inView ? COMMENTS_NODE_ID : '')

    return (
        <div ref={ref} className="min-h-[400px]">
            {inView ? <div id={COMMENTS_NODE_ID} /> : null}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I use `next-themes` to toggle `DarkMode`. I also send a request to utterances iframe so it doesn't load script twice but it still loads it twice by unmounting & mounting the component.

## DarkMode.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { useTheme } from 'next-themes'
import { MoonIcon, SunIcon } from '@heroicons/react/solid'

import { useHasMounted } from '@/hooks/index'
import { siteMetadata } from '@/_data/index'

export const DarkMode = () => {
    const { resolvedTheme, setTheme } = useTheme()
    const hasMounted = useHasMounted()

    const label = resolvedTheme === 'dark' ? 'Activate light mode' : 'Activate dark mode'

    if (!hasMounted) return null

    const toggleTheme = () => {
        const newTheme = resolvedTheme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'
        setTheme(newTheme)

        // for utterances
        const frame = document.getElementsByClassName('utterances-frame')[0] as HTMLIFrameElement
        if (frame?.contentWindow) {
            const utterancesTheme =
                resolvedTheme === 'light'
                    ? siteMetadata.comment.utterancesConfig.darkTheme
                    : siteMetadata.comment.utterancesConfig.theme
            frame.contentWindow.postMessage({ type: 'set-theme', theme: utterancesTheme }, '*')
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <button
                className="focus:outline-none"
                type="button"
                title={label}
                aria-label={label}
                onClick={toggleTheme}
            >
                {resolvedTheme === 'light' ? (
                    <MoonIcon className="w-8 h-8" />
                ) : (
                    <SunIcon className="w-8 h-8" />
                )}
            </button>
        </>
    )
}
```

How do I make sure it only requests script once? It now calls it everytime I toggle. It mounts and unmounts the component as I see nothing for a while when the script is loading.

GitHub repo -> https://github.com/deadcoder0904/next-utterances-script-loads-twice/tree/master

Stackblitz demo -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-6frqvs?file=pages%2Findex.tsx

Open in New Window to see the Dark Mode as Stackblitz currently doesn't support Tailwind Dark Mode. Check the Network Tab to see it sends request everytime even though you can also see the Comments component mounting & unmounting.

How do I only load script once?

Comment: You are doing a cleanup `scriptParentNode.removeChild` in your effect, so it will mount and unmount when the state changes in the tree above.

Comment: @PsyGik if I remove it, then it keeps adding more comment boxes below. what should i do in this case to make it work?

Comment: Off the top of my mind, you should probably add an `id` using `script.setAttribute` and only append the script if you don't find that `id` in the DOM. viz the script was added previously.

Comment: @PsyGik if I set that in `useUtterances.ts`, then in `Utterances.tsx` how can I reference the same `id` to know it came in the view like your `IntersectionObserver` blog post. It does makes sense to do that though but not sure how? The old way worked but I had to put the config outside in 1 place using `siteMetaData.ts` & it stopped working so hoping to find a solution for that.

Comment: @PsyGik got the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const scriptParentNode = document.getElementById(commentNodeId)
    const utterancesFrame = document.getElementsByClassName('utterances-frame')[0]
    if (!scriptParentNode || utterancesFrame) return

    // docs - https://utteranc.es/
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = 'https://utteranc.es/client.js'
    script.async = true
    script.setAttribute('repo', REPO_NAME)
    script.setAttribute('issue-term', 'pathname')
    script.setAttribute('label', 'comment :speech_balloon:')
    script.setAttribute('theme', utterancesTheme)
    script.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous')

    scriptParentNode.appendChild(script)
}, [REPO_NAME, commentNodeId, utterancesTheme])
```

So what basically is happen here. It is looks like when we append the utterances script after loading it replaces himself with:

```
<div class="utterances" style="height: 267px;">
    <iframe class="utterances-frame" title="Comments" scrolling="no" src="https://utteranc.es/..." loading="lazy"></iframe>
</div>
```

To avoid unnecessary append we check if there are some `<iframe class="utterances-frame"` already in the page and only if not append the script.

Comment: Nope, it does the same thing.

Comment: Ok i dig more into it and now i see the problem. Updated answer and made a fork: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-6frqvs-38nzlw?file=hooks%2FuseUtterances.ts Is it correct now?

Comment: damn it works now, what did you do? can you explain in the answer so I can upvote & accept it :)